# I can't sync my project to gradle, I have this error "Add google Maven repository and sync project"

Tags: android-studio, gradle, repository, build.gradle

I Tried adding these codes in my repositories:

```
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
```

but even now I can't sync gradle

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I opened an outdated learning project.

I took these steps to solve my problem:

**1. Add google Maven repository and sync project.**
[image: Add google Maven repository and sync project]

**2. Do refactor.**
[image: Do refactor]

**3. Update Gradle plugin and sync.**
[image: Update Gradle plugin and sync]

**(Optional) 4. If you opened an older project as I did in my example then don't forget to set up compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to your installed SDK version in build.gradle(Module:app) file.**

In my example, [this is my updated build.gradle(Project: "Project_name") file.](https://github.com/LaszloLajosT/Android_Me/blob/master/build.gradle)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my android studio 4.1, it dosn'e have "Do refactor" button, The error is shown in "Build" in the buttom of android studio , in tab "Sync", Please learn me how to access my Do refactor button!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was I was thinking that

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-alpha13'
```

in build.gradle, is same as

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

in gradle-wrapper.properties
so please go to project tab in project structure and set android gradle plugin version and gradle version in listbox and sync it again

Answer (score 0):

In the project's **build.gradle**, modify as follows:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven{ url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'} // <-- add
    //jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}



allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    maven{ url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'} // <-- add
    //jcenter()
}
}
```

**I hope this help**